# Targeting an element of closed/hidden form with DOM Manipulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have created a Chrome extension where I need to copy and paste (using 'keydown' event) the first `h1` and the `URL` of the current page I am on.

I tried to use `$document.queryselector` to target the element and then `$.innerText`, however, because the Chrome extension is (up and running but) hidden, `$.questySelector` returns null. Could not find any solution on Google. How would you solve this problem? Is there a way to set `$.innerText` of an hidden form?

Here is the simple form in HTML:

```
  <div>
    </div>
    <div id="myURL">
      <p>URL:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="myTitle">
      <p>Title:</p>
  </div>
```

And this is the logic in JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", logKey);
function logKey(e) {
  const myTitle = document.querySelector("#myTitle");
  if (e.code === "Digit1") {
    myTitle.innerText = "You pressed 1";
  } else {
    myTitle.innerText = "You pressed something else";
  }
}
```

This code works fine when my Chrome extension little window is open but it does not work when it is minimised and I press down the keys while I am on another web page using Chrome browser.

Hope it makes sense and thanks in advance for your help!

Gio

Comment: Would the intended operational mode be supported at all by the browser? Extracting / manipulating DOM data in the background is a potentially severe privacy issue, even more so  without giving the user a hint that it is happening

Comment: It is an extension that would be used by a community for their own research. I won't publish it online but I definitely see your point and can make sure that the popup will be displayed all the time while using the browser so that the user would be aware that it is running